# Animating UIStackView Subviews glitches to top left

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to animate subviews of a stackview (which are UIViews containing another stackview), when they enter and when they leave:

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear) {
    self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(someChildView) // same behaviour when hiding
    self.stackView.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

The problem I have is that it always enters from the top left of the screen and then grows.

I can't seem to figure out why it won't animate properly (it ignores the animated options completely, it always comes from the top left like in the GIF).

This is how the views are setup:

```swift
scrollView = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return scrollView
}()

stackView = {
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.distribution = .fill
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return stackView
}()

contentView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

contentView.addSubview(stackView)
scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
view.addSubview(scrollView)

scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
```

Question: It seems like the subviews don't know their width upon the start of the animation and only figures it out during it(?). How can I animate this properly?

Comment: You aren't really calling upon animatable properties in your animation block, likely what's animating is the stack view's frame changing as a new view is added into it (starting from x/y points of 0).  If you just want to gracefully display new views then first add the views to the stack view with a zero height, then in the animation block, expand the frame to whatever size it needs to be, and maybe add in an alpha change from 0 to 1 if you like that fading in look.

Comment: @SuperTully You are right, I changed the animation block to animate `isHidden = false` and `alpha = 1`. However, the issue of the elements originating from the top left still persist.

Answer (score 1):

What worked in the end and seems to be the solution for the elements originating from the top left of the screen is calling `view.layoutIfNeeded()`:

```swift
viewToAdd.alpha = 0
viewToAdd.isHidden = true
self.stackView.addArrangedSubview(viewToAdd)
self.view.layoutIfNeeded() // view is the very root view

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 5, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
    viewToAdd.isHidden = false
    viewToAdd.alpha = 1
}
```